# How do I replace onclick button to link format

Tags: jquery

Here is my current code

```
<input type="submit" value="Result" id="loadbutton" />

$.ajaxSetup ({
    cache: false
});
var ajax_load = "<img class='loading' src='/loading.gif' alt='loading...' />";

var loadUrl = "/result.php";
$("#loadbutton").click(function(){
    $("#result").html(ajax_load).load(loadUrl);
});
```

How to replace submit button

```
<input type="submit" value="Result" id="loadbutton" />
```

to be a link

```
<a href="/result.php">Result</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The normal way:

```
<a href="/result.php" id="result">Result</a>
<script>
    $('#result').click(function() {
        // Do something
     });
</script>
```

Comment: you mean $('#result').click()

Answer (score 1):

I think you're going around this the wrong way, trying to change the button into a link. It might be easier to just kill one and add the other. I'd do it this way:

```
<funzone><input type="submit" value="load()" id="loadbutton" /></funzone>
```

and then, as part of load()

```
$('funzone').remove('#loadbutton');
$('funzone').append('your image or whateves');
```

But that's just me. I mean, I'm the type of guy who makes up HTML tags, so, you know, grain of salt or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$("#loadbutton").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).replaceWith("<a href='/result.php'>Result</a>");
});
```

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/WVwc6/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<a href="javascript:document.[formname].submit()">submit the form</a>
```

Comment: Replace `[formname]` with your form name